# Constraint for multiple foreign key yet it's mutually exclusive (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, trigger, functions, constraint, check-constraints

Loan table associated to due table.

also

Invoice table associated to due table.

In due table either one of them foreign key should present and other one should be null.

What kind of constraint will be perfect ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it sounds, you cannot solve this with *one* constraint, but nothing prevents you from defining more of them.  I believe something like this should work:

```
CREATE TABLE due (
    ...,
    d_invoice_id REFERENCES invoice (i_id),
    d_loan_id REFERENCES loan (l_id),
    ...,
    CHECK (   (d_invoice_id IS NULL AND d_loan_id IS NOT NULL) 
           OR (d_invoice_id IS NOT NULL AND d_loan_id IS NULL))
);
```

A column that has a foreign key defined on does not have to be `NOT NULL`, unlike the column it references.  Apart from that, you may define checks of arbitrary complexity - it is advisable to keep complexity at its necessary minimum, though.

Answer (score -2):

I believe you cannot have such a contraint. You may have a column contraint or a table constraint. When working on foreign keys, they are on the table that "points" to the other table, and cannot use columns of other tables. So a constraint on table `invoice` can only check for `invoice` columns and cannot access `loan` columns.

You might work around the problem using triggers on both `load` and `invoice` tables. A trigger is function and can operate on any other table, beside the one it is attached.