# foreign key on multiple tables based on multiple columns

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key

I have a question about design part of my db I have 3 tables like these:

```
CREATE TABLTE projects (
    uuid uuid
    name text
)
CREATE TABLTE invoices (
    uuid uuid
    cost text
)
CREATE TABLTE fields (
    uuid uuid
    parent uuid REFERENCES (???) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    type varchar(255) (project or invoice)
)
```

is possible somehow to create one foreign key that look on more then one table and based on 2 columns (parent, type)? or do I need to do something like this?

```
CREATE TABLTE filds (
    uuid uuid
    project_uuid uuid REFERENCES projects(uuid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    invoice_uuid uuid REFERENCES invoices(uuid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional Foreign Key Relationship](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/113122/conditional-foreign-key-relationship). There is also [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/187608/flexible-foreign-key-constraint) question whose answers offer different approaches. Basically, you have to decide if you really need different tables for `projects` and `invoices`, or a single table with a `type` in it. The decision often depends on whether they have similar attributes or not.

Comment: the tables are logically different, so in my head they should be treated like different entity, and so I should not merge the 2 tables in one, but I'm open to change if it make sense, the other solution would be to use the "wordpress style" with a generic table "items" with a type column and another table "items_fields" but I'm not sure which of these 2 solution is better...do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

There are three ways:

1. If `projects` and `invoices` have almost the same columns and are ofhen used together like “get all projects or invoices that fulfill a certain condition” or “there must be a project or invoice that...”, then it is natural to model these two objects with a single table, introducing a column `type` to tell them apart.

   Then you can have a regular foreign key.
2. If they should be modeled as different tables and have different columns, introduce two foreign key columns in `fields`, ideally with a check constraint:

   ```
    CHECK (parent_invoice IS     NULL AND parent_project IS NOT NULL OR
           parent_invoice IS NOT NULL AND parent_project IS     NULL)
   ```
3. A hybrid solution would be

   ```
    CREATE TYPE p_or_i AS ENUM (
       'project',
       'invoice'
    );

    CREATE TABLE project_or_invoice (
       id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY NOT NULL,
       type p_or_i NOT NULL,
       /* other common columns */,
       PRIMARY KEY (id, type)
    );

    CREATE TABLE project (
       id bigint NOT NULL,
       type p_or_i GENERATED ALWAYS AS ('project') STORED NOT NULL,
       /* specific columns */,
       PRIMARY KEY (id, type),
       FOREIGN KEY (id, type) REFERENCES project_or_invoice
    );

    CREATE TABLE invoice (
       id bigint NOT NULL,
       type p_or_i GENERATED ALWAYS AS ('invoice') STORED NOT NULL,
       /* specific columns */,
       PRIMARY KEY (id, type),
       FOREIGN KEY (id, type) REFERENCES project_or_invoice
    );
   ```

   Then you would reference `project_or_invoice` in your foreign key.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I have a just a question about solution 2, is this acting like a foreign key? If I delete the parent row, will these row deleted too? thanks

Comment: That's not how a foreign key works unless you define it with `ON DELETE CASCADE`. But sure, if you define *both* foreign keys like that, that's how it will work. I didn't spell out the foreign keys in my second solution; I though that part was obvious.